# Pagination not working on basic webscraper

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

```
import scrapy


class BestBooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'best_books'
    page_num = 2
    allowed_domains = [
        'www.goodreads.com/list/show/1.Best_Books_Ever?page=1']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/1.Best_Books_Ever?page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        page_num = 2
        for books in response.xpath('//tr'):
            yield {
                'Title': books.css('a.bookTitle span::text').get(),
                'Author': books.css('a.authorName *::text').get(),
                'Rating': books.css('span.minirating::text').get(),
            }

        # this part is not working, won't read past page 1

        next_page = 'https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/1.Best_Books_Ever?page=' + \
            str(BestBooksSpider.page_num)
        if BestBooksSpider.page_num < 3:
            BestBooksSpider.page_num += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

First page works great, but it will not read subsequent pages. I've tried many different variations of the code from other tutorials without success. I'm not getting any error codes in scrapy. Scrapy just indicated it's finished.

Comment: What does the log say? Your `allowed_domains` is wrong to start…

Answer (score 0):

Your `allowed_domains` does look like it could be the reason for why pagination is not working.
`allowed_domains = ['www.goodreads.com/list/show/1.Best_Books_Ever?page=1']` should restrict your scraper to only the first page, so please go ahead and delete this line and try your spider again.